# How to disable magnifier from textformfield in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to disable Text Magnifier in TextFormField. Previously i was able to do but with TextField, I used  magnifierConfiguration property but unfortuantly this property is not available for TextFormField. Is there another way to disable it keeping into consideration that i still need the toolbar to appear (copy, paste, etc)?

Also I need to mention that the main reason i want to disable magnifier is because sometime the magnifier hangs and doesn't disappear and after some research I found that it's a known issue that was fixed on master but apparently not pushed to stable release yet.

Comment: i am unsure if this can be done on a textformfield, i am only sure of textfield, just like you mentioned above.